# Initializing Spring in not-web annotation-configured application

Tags: spring, annotations, applicationcontext

My java app is using Spring stereotype annotations (@Controller, @Component) and autowire annotations to manage dependency injections.

It is not web application, just plain jar. Also it's pure-annotation based code, i.e. no xml at all.

What is right way to initialize Spring annotation based application context and default configuration just from the main method?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use @Configuration to name a AppConfig which is equivalent to applicationContext.xml.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean(initMethod = "init")
  public Foo foo() {
      return new Foo();
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "cleanup")
  public Bar bar() {
      return new Bar();
  }
}
```

And in main method to new a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
  Foo foo = ctx.getBean(Foo.class);
  //etc
}
```

Comment: With @ComponentScan("com.company") annotation it answers question